# Access property of DataContext in ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

My datacontext has two properties: `Items` which is a collection and `DetailsVisiblity` which is **enum** of type `Visiblity`.

On the page I have a `Listbox` with `ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"`. Inside the `DataTemplate`, I can bind stuff to properties of Items, but how do I get access to `DetailsVisiblity` which is a property of `DataContext`?

`DataContext` has two properties: `ObservableCollection<Item> Entries`, and `Visibility DetailsVisiblity`. Item class has two properties: Title and Details.

Here is the view. How do I bind `Visiblity` of the second `TextBlock` to `DetailsVisiblity` property?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" Visibility="{Binding ???}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Please provide your class structure code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could name the ListBox and in the Binding you reference it with ElementName, and in Path you use DataContext.DetailsVisibility

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}"
                           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listBox,
                                                Path=DataContext.DetailsVisibilty}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @amrinder: Was this what you were after or did I missunderstand the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem which block me almost 2 hours (I'm a beginner on windows phone.)