# Adding images to StackPanel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF-application that is looking for new images in a database and if something comes up, it adds the image into a list. When that event is raised I want it to add the image into a StackPanel.

First I tried just to insert the image, but got an `InvalidOperationException` saying "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." and came up with:

```
public void Instance_GraphicChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Model.Graphic item in Model.IncomingCall.Instance.Graphics)
    {
        if(!_strings.Contains(item.ImageId.ToString()))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread( new ThreadStart(
                delegate()
                {
                    //sp_images StackPanel for Images
                    sp_images.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {
                                Image img = new Image();
                                img.Source = item.ImageObj; //ImageObj returns a BitmapImage
                                sp_images.Children.Add(img);
                            }
                    ));
                }
            ));
            _strings.Add(item.ImageId.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This does not throw any kind of exception, but actually nothing happens...

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new thread to invoke on the `Dispatcher`. Instead, you should call `sp_images.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)` with a delegate. Also, have you tried binding the image generation to an `ItemsControl`? You can use a template to turn that into a `StackPanel` and just work with `BitmapImage` objects contained within an `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to my comment, you could try something like this:

**XAML**

```
<!-- ... Other XAML Code ... -->
<ItemsControl x:Name="sp_images">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private readonly HashSet<string> mImageIds = new HashSet<string>();
private readonly ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> mImages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

// ... Inside the constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    sp_images.ItemsSource = mImages;
}

public void Instance_GraphicChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Model.Graphic item in Model.IncomingCall.Instance.Graphics)
    {
        // Have we already seen the image
        if (mImageIds.Add(item.ImageId.ToString()))
        {
            // We've not seen the image yet, so add it to the collection
            // Note: We must invoke this on the Dispatcher thread.
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                mImages.Add(item.ImageObj);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This should bypass any cross-thread exceptions you might have had before. It should also allow you to easily add new images to the [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), which will automatically update the UI with images. Also, the use of the `ItemTemplate` means you don't have to actually build the UI every time yourself; WPF will handle this for you.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) for more information on using the `ObservableCollection`. Also, refer to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581292/access-property-of-datacontext-in-itemtemplate) for an explanation on the container templating.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, and it looks like it is a large step on the way to a final solution, but I get an NotSupportedException where I add the imageObj to the mImages-collection.
Details says: "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

Comment: Ah yes, so it does. I have edited my answer to fix this issue.

Comment: And thank you again...
I now get Markup.XAMLParseException, and detail is: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.
I then tried to freeze the BitmapImage before adding it, and it told me that I couldn't access it because it was from another thread...
Again, thank your for your help...

Comment: Well, got it to work. Just needed to Freeze the image before I added it to the first list, and not when I took it out...

Thank you very much. You have been a great help...
Your answer should have been marked as correct...