# What is the BEST Way to display images in a ListBox WPF or Silverlight FROM a directory

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

**MY TASK:**
I have `ListBox` and `Grid`.
1. `ListBoxSource` and 2. `GridDetails` (with 2 columns and 2 rows) (This can be change to anything)
Now, all I want is to display the images in a `ListBox` (`ListBoxSource`) from a folder named "MyImages" and then I want those selected images from the `ListBoxSource`  **to TRANSFER** into another `ListBox` (`ListBoxDetails`) or `Grid` or whatever control that can handle it **AND** places the selected images to another directory called "MySelectedImages"

**My Problem:**
- Base on my scenario,
 HOW will I display/show my selected images to my `Grid` (define with 2 columns and 2 rows (total 4 cells)) and fill or add each cell with the selected image.

**Can someone show me some solution code or link related to my problem?** I will try to study it. 
I do have only basic learnings of C# and XAML. (I'm using Blend most of the time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a `DataTemplate` for the items inside your `ListBox` control. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for information on how to go about creating a `DataTemplate`. You then want to have some collection of images that you can build when reading from the folder and pass that collection to your `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` property. Refer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503246/adding-images-to-stackpanel-in-wpf/8503510#8503510) for more details on how to go about implementing this set up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I really appreciate it.
One more thing, What is the faster way to bind or load/bind images into a listBox? Creating an xml file of the images found? or Create a generic List?

Comment: I would imagine a generic list to save I/O operations on the XML file, but it all depends on your implementation.